# Deleting older dual boot version

Tags: 16.04

I did a fresh install of 16.04 along side 14.04 last summer. I am satisfied with 16.04 and want to remove 14.04 from GRUB and free up the disk space that 14.04 is occupying. What steps should I use?

Comment: [Remove old kernels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu), then delete the other system partition.

Comment: Is there a separate /boot partition, or is /boot only directory below /? Please post the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `df`to assist

Comment: I think editing the question in case there is more than one disk could also be helpful so please include lsblk as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool **[OS uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)**:

Steps:

1. boot computer on *live usb*
2. choose *try Ubuntu*
3. open a new terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and run the following command:

   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller`
4. Use os-uninstaller to remove Ubuntu 14.04:

   - launch os-uninstaller from *dash*
   - choose OS you want to remove and click ok/
   - [image]
   - on confirmation window click *Apply*
   - [image]

Source: [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)